# Heroku Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/index.html'

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, enoent

I deployed my nodejs app to Heroku
My project folder structure is as below
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNVrv.png)

Server.js

[Server.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z0nz.png)

After deployment I am getting above error as no such file or directory /app/index.html

I tried running run bash command to check folder structure on Heroku but it doesnt show me app folder at root path

[Heroku run bash output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNVRs.png)

wondering why I can't see app folder above where it is coming from?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this article first before asking (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as for the second: please provide your code via special (triple `) tags at the begging and at the end of your code. Don't use pics or links on them.

Comment: Sure.. I apologize as this was my first post I couldn’t realize. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index.html has a caps, you called it Index.html.

If you are using windows just notice you might have to delete Index.html, then push your project without it, then push it again with your file correctly named (index.html).

You are not seeing app/ because you are inside of it.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! It solved my issue. Seems file/directory names are case sensitive. It was working fine on dev machine so didn't realize that.

Comment: Glad to hear it !